# CSS or Javascript (not JQuery) solution for detecting resize height - see below the specific case

Tags: javascript, css, resize, height

I split in half a page sort of like in this pen:

https://codepen.io/sdras/pen/43c9d13b23bc34a85bb3a5e2ea985958

but disabled the snap on scroll (doesn't have full crossbrowser support) and made a switch button for cycling between the two halves (vertical navigation).
I kept most of the css from the pen (changed it a bit, only).

The problem is that on resize it shows the content from the current viewport, and part from the one above, in the first instance. As soon as I navigate, though, it takes the correct height. This problem is also in the pen above - try navigating down, then change the window height and then change it back again, and you will see a portion of the screen above is also displayed.

Any thoughts on how I can fix this?

Thanks!

PS: I also do not wish to reload the content of the page. I've Already tried scrolling down to the end of the page and it is not working: `window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);`

Comment: Found a solution just after giving up:

 `document.querySelector(".adjust-container-height").scrollIntoView(true);`

This scrolls the page to the bottom on resize. Now I just need to figure out where the user is and either scrollIntoView top or bottom. 

Thanks! I'll leave this here, maybe it will help someone at some point.

Comment: If you keep a reference to the current element you last scrolled to, then you can solve this by adding a 'onresize' listener that will simply scroll to the top of that element. This way, it doesn't matter if the size of the element changes - you simply scroll to it to show it on the screen.

Comment: Excellent idea! Thank you!